# Where to watch My Hero Academia: Heroes Rising in the UK

Tags: my-hero-academia

Im looking to watch the new film Heroes Rising in the UK. Ive seen alot of articles that it was available in the cinema at the end of Febaury/March time but i must have missed the promotion about that since i never heard anyhting about it.

Is there another way for me to see it ? I have no qualms about paying or buying the blue-ray etc if needed. I just cant seem to find any information about it.

Comment: Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you missed it on theaters, the Blu-ray and DVD is releasing on **July 15**, according to the film's [official twitter account](https://twitter.com/heroaca_movie?s=09).

[image]